# MySQL - how to reorder records depending on counted quantity

Tags: mysql, count

Please help me to figure out how to get table like this:

```
ID  Name    City
--  ----    ----
1   A       2       
2   C       1
3   E       3
4   B       2
5   D       2
6   G       3
7   F       2
```

... to be sorted like this:

```
ID  Name    City
--  ----    ----
1   A       2   
4   B       2
5   D       2
7   F       2   
3   E       3
6   G       3
2   C       1
```

in other words I'd like it to be reordered depending on quantity of Names in a City firstly, and by Name secondly. 
Cities having more Names should go first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select c.* from c 
inner join (
  select City, count(*) as cnt from c group by City
) a
on c.City = a.City
order by a.cnt desc, c.name asc
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59f56/6)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID,NAME,CITY,(select count(*) from  AS T2 where T2.CITY = T1.CITY) as CITYCOUNT FROM  AS T1 order by CITYCOUNT DESC,NAME ;

OR

SELECT ID,NAME,CITY FROM  AS T1 order by (select count(*) from  AS T2 where T2.CITY = T1.CITY)DESC,NAME ;

**Alternatively you can also do this:**

ALTER TABLE  ADD COLUMN CITYCOUNT INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

UPDATE  T1 (select CITY,count(*) as CITYCOUNT from  group by CITY)  T2 SET T1.CITYCOUNT = T2.CITYCOUNT where T1.CITY = T2.CITY;

SELECT ID,NAME,CITY,CITYCOUNT FROM  AS T1 order by CITYCOUNT DESC,NAME

Answer (score -1):

I think your example is not correct, Cities with Value 3 should come on Top, for this you can try this query:

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, City
FROM <TABLE>
ORDER BY City DESC, Name ASC;
```

Hope this is what you want.

Updated Answer:

```
SELECT
    Id, Name, T.City
FROM <TABLE> T
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT
    City, Count(City) AS CITYCOUNT
FROM Table_7
GROUP BY City) TEMP ON TEMP.City = T.City
ORDER BY TEMP.CITYCOUNT DESC
```

Comment: No, I need Cities that have **higher quantity of Names** to come on top.

Comment: apparently what author wants is to have table rows sorted by number of Names that have equal City value. Like A, B, D, F forms a group of four and so go before E, G which form a group of two.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood